# Parse Cloud Code Alternatives

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, firebase, parse-cloud-code

I have been doing a lot of research of alternatives to Parse's Cloud Code but can't seem to find a solid one. I already moved everything to Firebase but need a Cloud Code alternative to run some other things.

What would be my best options to call a Cloud Code method type for an iOS/Android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase just released [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), which allows you to run JavaScript functions on Google's servers in response to Firebase events (such as database changes, users signing in and much more). It covers a different set of use-cases than Parse's Cloud Code though, so you will have to modify your code to fit.

Comment: I saw that yesterday! I'm so excited to get my hands on with their new cloud code.

Comment: Good to hear Mitch! If you have any problems, just open a new question.